# android location permissions not applied with product flavors

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm developing an app with two product flavors, one flavor has a map feature, when i wanted to use location services i started by setting `map.isMyLocationEnabled = true` Android studio shows an error indicating that ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION or ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permissions are required.

I added both permissions in the flavor Manifest.xml in the first time, but didn't work, then i added it to the main Manifest.xml it didn't work, i tried also to put them in both xml files it didn't work, do you have an idea how to solve this issue?

**UPDATE:**
here is my Manifest files and gradle flavors configs:

- The manifest file of the flavor that will implement maps feature

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:name="APP_NAME"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:fullBackupOnly="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="THEME"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
    
    <!--Activities -->

</application>
```

- the other flavor(it's stil empty):

```
<!-- add theme and application class-->
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:supportsRtl="true" />
```

- the main Manifest File:

the flavors config in buid.gradle (app):

```
flavorDimensions "DIMENSION"
productFlavors{
    ep...{
        dimension "DIMENSION"
        applicationId "APP_ID"
        applicationIdSuffix "FLAVOR_SUFFIX"
    }
    amb...{
        dimension "DIMENSION"
        applicationId "APP_ID"
        applicationIdSuffix "FLAVOR_SUFFIX"
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your manifest file code? Have you tried following the Maps SDK for Android documentation? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/location#add_the_permissions_to_the_app_manifest

Comment: hey @jabamataro check my updated question.